# friendly url only opens the post.php not cat.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Friends, what is the right way to get both the php files to open friendly URL contents?

My current code works OK if I only use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but then I also need friendly URL for my categories so I tried to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but doing so only the post URL opens but category links redirect back to index.php but if you remove the rewrite for post than the cat.php contents shows.

If someone could help me out here would really appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your use of the `[L]` flag.

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

[Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

Instead, try and have your rules laid out like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i get page not found but when i remove the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L] then index.php contents are showing

Comment: r u there mate?